# Identification of events in SF1 or App

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning, event

I am trying to fire some navigation events which can run in both SF1 application or in custom lightning app. Now I checked this link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_one.htm

where it has been given as

```
displayToast : function (component, event, helper) {
    var toast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    if (toast){
        //fire the toast event in Salesforce1
        toast.setParams({
            "title": "Success!",
            "message": "The component loaded successfully."
        });
        toast.fire();
    } else {
        //your toast implementation for a standalone app here
    }
}
```

ACTUAL CODE

```
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");


console.log('urlEvent -->', urlEvent);
    if (urlEvent) {
        urlEvent.setParams({
          "recordId": event.target.dataset.articleid
        });
        urlEvent.fire();    
    } else {
        console.log('not SF1');
        window.location.href = articleurl;
    }
```

But on similar lines if I write the code, it always go to if statement and never goes to else.

Any idea how can i understand the difference in firing of events?

Thanks
Ray

Comment: Are you accessing your app as `instance.lightning.force.com/namespace/AppName.app`? If you created a link to it in Lightning Experience, or you're accessing it through Salesforce1, it will toast. I've just written up a Lightning App that uses your code basically identically, and it works as expected.

Comment: I have created a custom application includig my component in it. THe url for app is something like this - https://kaushik-demo1.lightning.force.com/c/TestKnowledgeArticleApplication.app

Comment: Also I tried by adding the component to Community directly using builder, somehow at both places it behaves as if it is in SF1 app and it gets the event